# Creating a blank document in a document library using client object model

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office365

I'm creating a  function where you can provide a content type name and target either a list or document library and create a default item. Im using the client object model for office 2013

```
public void MyFunction()
{
   //clientContext must be authenticated already on your sharepoint site

   var listName = "Default Document Set";
   var docSetContentTypeName = "Document";
   var newDocSetName = string.Format("Item {0}", Guid.NewGuid());

   Web web = clientContext.Web;
   List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site);

   ContentTypeCollection listContentTypes = list.ContentTypes;
   clientContext.Load(listContentTypes, types => types.Include
                              (type => type.Id, type => type.Name,
                              type => type.Parent));

   var result = clientContext.LoadQuery(listContentTypes.Where
    (c => c.Name == docSetContentTypeName));

   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   ContentType targetDocumentSetContentType = result.FirstOrDefault();

   ListItemCreationInformation newItemInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
   newItemInfo.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
   newItemInfo.LeafName = newDocSetName;
   ListItem newListItem = list.AddItem(newItemInfo);

   newListItem["ContentTypeId"] = targetDocumentSetContentType.Id.ToString();
   newListItem["Title"] = newDocSetName;
   newListItem.Update();

   clientContext.Load(list);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The function works fine on ContentTypes like Item and Document Set but when I use Document, it creates an item with a content type "Document" but it has an icon of folder and acts like a folder. 
[image: Document Type]

Is there something I need to add?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[FileSystemObjectType.Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filesystemobjecttype%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is used for creating a `Folder` object and therefore could **not** be specified for creating `File` object. At the same time [List.AddItem Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.additem%28v=office.14%29.aspx) could **not** be used for creating a *File object*.

You could consider the following example that demonstrates how to create(upload) a file into Documents library:

```
public static void UploadFile(List list,string filePath,IDictionary<string,object> itemProperties)
{
        var ctx = list.Context;
        var fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
        fileInfo.Url = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
        fileInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
        var listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
        foreach (var p in itemProperties)
        {
            listItem[p.Key] = p.Value;
        }    
        listItem.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Using [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) you could create an empty document and upload it into Documents library:

```
public static void CreateAndUploadFile(List list, string filePath, IDictionary<string, object> itemProperties)
{
    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        var mainPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
        mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());
    }
    UploadFile(list, filePath, itemProperties);
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var itemProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>();
itemProperties["Title"] = "SharePoint User Guide";
CreateAndUploadFile(list, "./SharePoint User Guide.docx", itemProperties);
```